# TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in (Flask Framework)

Tags: python, flask

kindly help it out folks! I am new to programming. I am trying to Authenticate Login. But its showing **"TypeError....."** i couldn't figure out.

See Below This is My code (main.py)

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('EMAIL')
        con1 = sqlite3.connect("check10.db")
        cur = con1.cursor()
        data = cur.execute("SELECT EMAIL FROM register WHERE EMAIL = ? ", (email,))
        if data == email:
            return render_template('homepage.html')
        else:
            alert = "Check Credentials "
            return render_template('loginpage.html', alert)
    return render_template("loginpage.html")
```

Comment: You should edit the question and add the full error code received.

Comment: By watching the code it looks like is a TypeError because of the sqlite3 execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 from flask import request, render_template, flash

 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
     if request.method == 'POST':
         email = request.values.get('EMAIL')
         con1 = sqlite3.connect("check10.db")
         cur = con1.cursor()
         data = cur.execute("SELECT EMAIL FROM register WHERE EMAIL = ? ", (email,))
         if data == email:
             return render_template('homepage.html')
         else:
             flash('Check Credentials ')
             return render_template('loginpage.html')
  return render_template("loginpage.html")
```

Try also to change the variable email like:

```
email = request.args.get('EMAIL')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because of `return render_template('loginpage.html', alert)`.

If you want to send some data from server to HTML page then you can refer to [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object).

If you want flash message 'check credentials' to the user then refer to this [Link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/#simple-flashing)

Comment: **Bro, i tried that too.  I couldn't get it.
if possible can U recode it**